# python mocking function calls that are called during module import

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, python-mock

I need to perform mocking for python code that is running during module import

For example I have code like this

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('test.ini')
a = float(config['config']['a'])
b = float(config['config']['b'])
c = float(config['config']['c'])

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

I need mock "config" for testing

```
import pytest
import mock

import app

@mock.patch('app.configparser.ConfigParser')
def test_config_mock(config_mock):
     config_mock.return_value = {'config': { 'a' : 1 } }
```

However, this testing function being called after actual import so my mocking is not making any sense

What's the right way of doing this kind of thing?

Comment: The right way to do it is simply *not* on import. Expose a function that does that, then call it `if __name__ == •"__main__":`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe , sorry I am not sure I understand how mocking question relates to your answer. If I put import statement into function and make function call from if __name__ == "__main__" I will get into the same issue. The module will be loaded before actual test function executed.

Comment: I'm not saying put an import in a function in the test, if that's what you mean; I'm saying *modify `app.configparser`* so that you can import its functionality *without* immediately executing it.

Comment: @jonsharpe, ok now it's clear, you mean to modify code under test. 
But again, it seems that this will not work either.  A,B,C variables will be defined only in if's scope but they are used in other functions of this module. This means refactoring the module code which is not the favorable option.  Could you please post a code snippet (might b a pseudocode) if possible?

Comment: Of course it means refactoring the module code. You've written code that isn't testable; if you want to test it, you'll need to refactor it.

Comment: I'm not saying this pattern is good. But what you can do is to mock the instance `config` instead. Then code using that config should pick up the mocking.

Comment: that's what I actually did : ) thanks for answering though

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in this case is to instead patch the `config` instance using [`mock.patch.dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-dict):

```py
# test_coolio.py
import mock
from app.fun import coolio


@mock.patch.dict('app.configparser.config', values={'config': {'a': 15}})
def test_config_mock():
    assert coolio() == '15'


# app/fun.py
from app.configparser import config


def coolio():
    return config['config']['a']
```